# Angular: Sort by list of properties with mixed ASC and DESC

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I have an ng-repeat and I'm trying to get a specific order. I see that I can order using a list of properties:

```
ng-repeat="client in clients | orderBy: ['isOpen', 'lastAccessTime']"
```

My question is, how do I configure ascending and descending?

I want the primary sort on `isOpen` with DESC, and secondary sort on `lastAccessTime` with ASC. How can I achieve this in my `ng-repeat`?

EDIT: I tried this below but, but when two items are both `isOpen`, the highest `lastAccessTime` is not on top:

```
ng-repeat="client in clients | orderBy: 'isOpen':true | orderBy: 'lastAccessTime'"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can prefix the property name with a `+` or `-` to indicate either ascending or descending order, as specified [in the documentation for `orderBy`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3aorderBy).

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array and optionally prefixed with + or - to control ascending or descending sort order

`ng-repeat="client in clients | orderBy: ['isOpen','-lastAccessTime']"`